# SetFilePointerEx get file size

Tags: c, winapi

I am new in programming, especially in Windows System Programming and I 'm reading a relevant book. Currently I 'm playing arround with GetFileSizeEx, [SetFilePointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SetFilePointerEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542(v=vs.85).aspx) in order to get the file size of a file.

I have created this code that works until line 65 where I can't get SetFilePointerEx to work to get the size.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 0x100

// program to test file size

int _tmain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR argv[])
{
    HANDLE hIn;
    HANDLE hOut;
    LARGE_INTEGER liSize;
    LONG lSize, lDistance = 0;
    TCHAR szMsgGetFile[BUFF_SIZE];
    TCHAR szMsgSetFile[BUFF_SIZE];
    DWORD nIn;
    LARGE_INTEGER liPt;
    PLARGE_INTEGER pLi;
    pLi = &liPt;

    SecureZeroMemory(&liSize, sizeof(LARGE_INTEGER));
    SecureZeroMemory(&pLi, sizeof(LARGE_INTEGER));
    SecureZeroMemory(szMsgGetFile, _tcslen(szMsgGetFile));
    SecureZeroMemory(szMsgSetFile, _tcslen(szMsgSetFile));


    //get input and output handles
    hIn = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hIn == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        _tprintf(_T("[ERROR] CreateFile to get file input handle failed. Error code %d.\n"), GetLastError());
    hOut = CreateFile(_T("CONOUT$"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        _tprintf(_T("[ERROR] CreateFile to get file output handle failed. Error code %d.\n"), GetLastError());

    //get the size of the file with GetFileSizeEx, acquired from hIn that is argv1
    if (!GetFileSizeEx(hIn, &liSize))
        _tprintf(_T("[ERROR] GetFileSizeEx failed. Error code %d\n"), GetLastError());

    //get the size of the file with SetFilePointer
    //You can obtain the file length by specifying a zero-length move from the end of
    //file, although the file pointer is changed as a side effect
    lSize = SetFilePointer(hIn, lDistance, NULL, FILE_END);
    if (lSize == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
        _tprintf(_T("[ERROR] SetFilePointer failed. Error code %d\n"), GetLastError());

    //output the size with WriteConsole (and sprintf)
    //and with _tprintf. Notice the usage of the liSize LARGE_INTEGER
    _stprintf_s(szMsgGetFile, BUFF_SIZE, "[*] GetFileSizeEx (WriteConsole): The size is %I64d Bytes.\n", liSize.QuadPart);
    if (!WriteConsole(hOut, szMsgGetFile, _tcslen(szMsgGetFile), &nIn, NULL))
        _tprintf(_T("[ERROR] WriteConsole failed. Error code %d\n"), GetLastError());
    _tprintf(_T("[*] GetFileSizeEx (tprintf): The size is %I64d Bytes.\n"), liSize.QuadPart);

    //output the size with WriteConsole (and sprintf)
    //and _tprintf
    _stprintf_s(szMsgSetFile, BUFF_SIZE, "[*] SetFilePointer (WriteConsole): The size is %ld Bytes.\n", lSize);
    if (!WriteConsole(hOut, szMsgSetFile, _tcslen(szMsgSetFile), &nIn, NULL))
        _tprintf(_T("[ERROR] WriteConsole failed. Error code %d\n"), GetLastError());
    _tprintf(_T("[*] SetFilePointer (tprintf): The size is %ld Bytes.\n"), lSize);

    //get the size of the file with SetFilePointerEx
    //Determine a file’s size by positioning 0 bytes from the end and using the file
    //pointer value returned by SetFilePointerEx.
    SecureZeroMemory(&liPt, sizeof(LARGE_INTEGER));
    SetFilePointerEx(hIn, liPt, pLi, FILE_END);
    _tprintf(_T("[*] SetFilePointerEx: %lld Bytes.\n"), pLi->QuadPart);
    return 0;
}
```

MSDN says that

> You can use SetFilePointerEx to determine the length of a file. To do this, use FILE_END for dwMoveMethod and seek to location zero. The file offset returned is the length of the file.

However, SetFilePointerEx is of type BOOL. The "Windows System Programming" book says that the "Determine a file’s size by positioning 0 bytes from the end and using the file pointer value returned by SetFilePointerEx.". I am guessing that this parameter is the `_Out_opt_ PLARGE_INTEGER lpNewFilePointer` according to MSDN.

I would like help on how to get the file size of the file by using SetFilePointerEx.

Comment: I believe your usage of `SetFilePointerEx` in your code is correct. The filesize should be `pLI->QuadPart`.

Comment: you are fast :) thanks - indeed I had

Comment: The program crashes after showing the SetFilePointer tprintf output. When trying to debug it (i 'm a noob at using the vs debugger) it reports that pLi is nullptr

Comment: pLi _is_ null. You're never setting it. See my answer for the correct way to do this.

Comment: `SecureZeroMemory(&pLi, sizeof(LARGE_INTEGER));` here is double error. at first you zero `pLi` (after you set `pLi = &liPt;`) at second need not `sizeof(LARGE_INTEGER)` but `sizeof(PLARGE_INTEGER)`. then no sense zero vars at all here. especially with SecureZeroMemory

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I forgot to remove that part before posting... Many different tries to make it work created bloat =[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of errors in your code. Here's an example of `SetFilePointerEx` that works. In general, Win32 functions don't allocate the memory to store their output (some do). It's up to the caller to allocate memory. In this case, the memory for the output of `SetFilePointerEx` is allocated on the stack by declaring `size2` to be a `LARGE_INTEGER`. A pointer to that `LARGE_INTEGER` is then provided to `SetFilePointerEx`.

```
auto hIn = CreateFile(_T("C:\\foo"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
/* check for errors */

LARGE_INTEGER size;
GetFileSizeEx(hIn, &size);
/* check for errors */

LARGE_INTEGER size2;
LARGE_INTEGER offset;
ZeroMemory(&offset, sizeof offset);
SetFilePointerEx(hIn, offset, &size2, FILE_END);
/* check for errors */
```

Comment: Your code works, thanks! I would like some more info regarding my errors, if you 'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, `DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);` can get the size of the file opened by `HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA/W(...);`.